# "Segfault using proj4 with OpenMP" or "How to use thread-specific globals with OpenMP"

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, proj

I have a large number of objects defined by WGS84 coordinates which I would like to transform into Mercator space. There are other operations not shown in the MWE which prevent me from just doing everything in a single-threaded manner.

My current code is as follows:

```cpp
//Compile with: g++ -O3 temp.cpp -lproj -fopenmp
#include <proj_api.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <cmath>

typedef std::vector<double>  dvec;
typedef std::pair<dvec,dvec> dvpair;

//Define these here so we're not making them every time we run `pj_transform()`
const char* wgs84_str = "+init=epsg:4326";
const char* merc_str  = "+init=epsg:3857";
const projPJ pj_wgs84 = pj_init_plus(wgs84_str);
const projPJ pj_merc  = pj_init_plus(merc_str);

//Use the global projections to do projecty stuff
void ToMercator(std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &y){
  pj_transform(pj_wgs84, pj_merc, x.size(), 1, x.data(), y.data(), NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  std::vector<dvpair> dvs(1000);
  for(int i=0;i<dvs.size();i++){
    dvs[i].first.push_back(2*M_PI*rand()-M_PI);  //Longitude in [-180,180]
    dvs[i].second.push_back(M_PI*rand()-M_PI/2); //Latitude in [-90,90]
  }

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i=0;i<dvs.size();i++)
    ToMercator(dvs[i].first,dvs[i].second);
}
```

But it segfaults with a [heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug). Getting a core dump with `ulimit -c unlimited` shows that `pj_transform` is raising the problem. This isn't too mysterious since some digging showed that proj4 is not thread safe.

The way to fix this is to create per-thread contexts for proj4 [per this site](http://proj4.org/threads.html). And this brings us to the meet of the problem.

Each thread needs to run `pj_ctx_alloc()` which will return a thread-specific variable of type `projCtx`, which then needs to be used with `pj_init_plus_ctx()` to make the `projPJ` objects responsible for the coordinate transforms.

How can I create thread-specific globals in OpenMP?

(You will want to answer that "globals are bad". I understand this, but note that removing them doesn't fundamentally change the question. I also have an aversion to "[tramp data](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tramp_data)". In my actual application there are at least six layers of intermediate functions before I reach `pj_transform()`: I have a preference for not passing parameters that deep in this instance. You may disagree with the design choice, but this is not the right venue to argue about it.)

**Edit** This also did not work:

```
#include <proj_api.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <cmath>

typedef std::vector<double>  dvec;
typedef std::pair<dvec,dvec> dvpair;

//Define these here so we're not making them every time we run `pj_transform()`
const char* wgs84_str = "+init=epsg:4326";
const char* merc_str  = "+init=epsg:3857";
projPJ  pj_wgs84;
projPJ  pj_merc;
projCtx pj_ctx;

//Use the global projections to do projecty stuff
void ToMercator(std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &y){
  pj_transform(pj_wgs84, pj_merc, x.size(), 1, x.data(), y.data(), NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  std::vector<dvpair> dvs(1000);
  for(int i=0;i<dvs.size();i++){
    dvs[i].first.push_back(2*M_PI*rand()-M_PI);  //Longitude in [-180,180]
    dvs[i].second.push_back(M_PI*rand()-M_PI/2); //Latitude in [-90,90]
  }

  #pragma omp parallel private(pj_ctx, pj_wgs84, pj_merc)
  {
    pj_ctx   = pj_ctx_alloc();
    pj_wgs84 = pj_init_plus_ctx(pj_ctx,wgs84_str);
    pj_merc  = pj_init_plus_ctx(pj_ctx,merc_str);

    #pragma omp for
    for(int i=0;i<dvs.size();i++)
      ToMercator(dvs[i].first,dvs[i].second);
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Using:

```
projPJ  pj_wgs84;
projPJ  pj_merc;
projCtx pj_ctx;
#pragma omp threadprivate(pj_wgs84)
#pragma omp threadprivate(pj_merc)
#pragma omp threadprivate(pj_ctx)

...

#pragma omp parallel private(pj_ctx, pj_wgs84, pj_merc)
{
  pj_ctx   = pj_ctx_alloc();

...
```

Gives a linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: pj_merc: TLS definition in /tmp/ccqZRl8N.o section .tbss mismatches non-TLS definition in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so section .text
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You're looking for `threadprivate`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347008/confused-about-firstprivate-and-threadprivate-in-openmp-context

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```cpp
#include <proj_api.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <cmath>

typedef std::vector<double>  dvec;
typedef std::pair<dvec,dvec> dvpair;

//Define these here so we're not making them every time we run `pj_transform()`
const char* wgs84_str = "+init=epsg:4326";
const char* merc_str  = "+init=epsg:3857";

//Using static means that these variables are file-scope. If we didn't use
//static then the variables might be accessed across many files and OpenMP would
//not like that
static projPJ  pj_wgs84;
static projPJ  pj_merc;
static projCtx pj_ctx;

//Set it so each thread has its own, private copy
#pragma omp threadprivate(pj_wgs84)
#pragma omp threadprivate(pj_merc)
#pragma omp threadprivate(pj_ctx)

//Use the global projections to do projecty stuff
void ToMercator(std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &y){
  pj_transform(pj_wgs84, pj_merc, x.size(), 1, x.data(), y.data(), NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  std::vector<dvpair> dvs(10000);
  for(int i=0;i<dvs.size();i++){
    dvs[i].first.push_back(2*M_PI*rand()-M_PI);  //Longitude in [-180,180]
    dvs[i].second.push_back(M_PI*rand()-M_PI/2); //Latitude in [-90,90]
  }

  //Do this somewhere convenient ... like here
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    pj_ctx   = pj_ctx_alloc();
    pj_wgs84 = pj_init_plus_ctx(pj_ctx,wgs84_str);
    pj_merc  = pj_init_plus_ctx(pj_ctx,merc_str);
  }

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i=0;i<dvs.size();i++)
    ToMercator(dvs[i].first,dvs[i].second);
}
```

**Sad news**: Testing this on a machine with more cores (24 vs 4) still led to segfaults.